# How can I disable the default tvOS focus animations?

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield, tvos, focus-engine

I need to create a UI which is a mix of `UITableView`, `UITextField`, and some custom `UIView`'s and I also need to provide a custom focus animation.

How can I get the `UITableView`/`UITableViewCell` and `UITextField` to not render the default focus animations?

I tried:

```
    override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        if let view = context.previouslyFocusedView {
            view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        }
        if let view = context.nextFocusedView {
            view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        }
    }
```

I can add my own animations, but can't get rid of the 'default' animations from the view.

Comment: If you subclass them you should be able to override the animations.

Comment: I've tried to override/delete animations to no avail.

Comment: Describe the animations you are seeing. Putting you code in a `UITableViewCell` subclass removed all animations for me. Though the `removeAllAnimations()` calls are unnecessary.

Comment: I'm referring to the slightly scaled up and drop shadow effect that tvOS draws for the currently focused view.

Comment: Did you figure this out? @pstoppani

Answer (score 2):

Change the focus style of the cell to custom instead of default.

```
cell.focusStyle = UITableViewCellFocusStyle.custom
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove focus from UITableViewCells, use this code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The question is asking how can one disable the default focus animation not prevent focusing on an item.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem with which is similar to your question but my `UITableView` which has just one `UITableViewCell`. So when UIViewController present / load there is no focused UITableViewCell and when I click cell it perform its action ( present an `UIAlertController`)

```
    if let focusedCell = UIScreen.main.focusedView as? MyCell{

         focusedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
```

then

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // take action
    ... alertController configuration
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {

          tableView.reloadData()

    })

}
```

When table has reloaded itself it convert its not focused form and the cycle is repeat itself.